# Split Java.Brackets and spaces

Tags: java

I can not divide a string by delimiters `*/.- +()`. That's what I tried, but the problem with brackets and spaces:

`arr = str.split("\\.|\\*|\\+|\\(|\\)|\\s|\\-|\\/");`

Comment: Could add example of source string and result string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex.

```
[ */.-/+()]
```

Test Class.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(final String... args) {
      final String string = "ss2/0+1s.s7";
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split("[ */.-/+()]")));
   }
}
```

*Edited after OP updated question.*

Comment: What negation?? I don't understand. Provide a before and after string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea using bellow code,

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String mySring = "part1==part2++part3=part4+part5.part6*part7-part8";
    String[] variables= mySring.split("(==)|(=)|(\\++)|(\\+)|(\\.)|(\\*)|(\\-)");

    for(int i =0 ; i<variables.length ;i++){
        System.out.println(variables[i]);
    }
}
```